# starting a new section with bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I want to add a new section with images/text that do not overlap my other sections
for example this is section one.
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eSlL.png
and this is section two:
[enter image description here][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/seBGm.png

as you can see there is a different section that fills the whole screen(width and height of chrome tab). they are not 2 different html pages, they are in the same html file.
here is proof:
[enter image description here][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwCiK.png

```
<body class="h-100 d-flex flex-column">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark py-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-brand mx-auto"><h2 style="color: white;">Name</h2></div>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#burger"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="burger">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#python" class="nav-link px-3"><h2 style="color: white;">Python</h2></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-3"><h2 style="color: white;">Name</h2></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#html&css" class="nav-link px-3"><h2 style="color: white;">Html&Css</h2></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--Secion One-->
    <section class="bg-dark d-flex align-items-center flex-1 text-light p-5 p-lg-0 text-center text-md-start">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">
                <h1 class="hi">Design made by the <span style="color: #F23DFF;">youth</span></h1>
            </div>
                <div class="align-items-center text-center position-relative position-absolute top-50 start-0 translate-middle-y">
                    <h3 class="languages">About</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="align-items-center text-center position-relative position-absolute top-50 end-0 translate-middle-y">
                    <h3 class="languages">Langs</h3>
                </div>
        </div>            
    </section>
    <!--section Two-->
    <section class="justify-content-center d-flex">
        <div class="container position-absolute h-100">
            <svg class="svgOne" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 600 600" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <rect width="600" height="600" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
                </svg>
                <h1 class="textOne">Never regret anything 
                    that made you smile.
                    </h1>
          </div>
      </section>
    <!--Section Three-->
    <section class="justify-content-center d-flex">
        <div class="container position-absolute h-100">
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `row` class to create horizontal sections. For more information, you can check the bootstrap's [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).